# Wall texturing without slides

Tags: texturing, uv

My problem is the following:
I have a wall wich I textured with a Uv Map. Because I dont wanna have N-gons in it, I made a triangle. But do you know any other way to texture the wall without any extra slides (in UV map) and without n-gons? [image]

Thanks for your help - this forum helps a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it this way. There is only one additional vertex than the original and it's quad based modeling which has a lot of advantages.

Because it is flat unwrap it using "Project From View".

[image: Project From View]

[image]